# why are there so many duplicate words in url

Tags: http, url, dns, web

Like this one, why are there so many duplicate words in url?
http://medicine.uiowa.edu/biochemistry/proteomics/biochemistry/biochemistry/biochemistry/biochemistry/biochemistry/node/451

Even when I add more biochemistry, it still works! Anyone can explain?

Answer (score 1):

I used Chrome's Network Inspector, but all browsers have this capability. When a request is made to https://medicine.uiowa.edu/biochemistry/, the response code is a nice 200. If you hit https://medicine.uiowa.edu/biochemistry/proteomics/, you'll see that you get a 301, meaning that this link has been moved permanently, and you can see that you've been redirected to just `/biochemistry` again.

[image: 301 Explained]

You may also get a 304, which tells the browser to simply get the content from a different location without retransmitting any information. Indeed, it appears you can add *any* number of `/proteomics` or `/biochemistry` to the URL and it will go to the same place. My guess is that whoever set up the web server rules used a flawed regular expression for routing.